# Previous/Next functions for js slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have almost finished this slider, but I don't know how to implement the functionality for `next()` and `prev()`. How can I implement these functions?

Also, if I add more than 3 slides to the slider, then it stops working correctly. How can I deal with more than 3 slides?

http://jsfiddle.net/M4t4L/3/

```
$(function () {

    var container = $("#scene"),
        i = 0,
        count = container.find("li").length,
        j = container.find("li").length - 1,
        isAnimating = false;

    container.find("li:first").css({
        "width": "100%"
    });

    $("#trigger").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(e);

        i++;
        if (i >= count) {
            i = 0;
        }
        j++;
        if (j >= count) {
            j = 0;
        }

        container.find("li")
            .finish()
            .removeClass('active')
            .eq(2)
            .width(0)
            .addClass("active")
            .animate({
            "width": "100%"
        }, 400,

        function () {
            container.find("li").first().appendTo(container);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Come on guys. Voting to close because he didn't paste the JSFiddle code here? Really? Give the newbie a chance :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie no voting to close because "halp I don't know how to implement X" is not a specific question. And we have no idea what specific part to answer because there is no question

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Retracted the vote.

Comment: @PeeHaa: How about "I add a slider more than 3 slides, then he begins to work not correctly"? (ignoring grammar sounds like a problem to solve :))

Comment: No cookie for you. "not work correctly" is not a sufficient problem description and does not contain any useful info besides "it does not work"

Comment: @PeeHaa I am French, I don't speak English. Sorry

Comment: @PeeHaa: I WANT A COOKIE! :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie `javascript:alert(document.cookie);` there ya go. Have a cookie!

Comment: You can also change to a delta change style of logic. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/M4t4L/7/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie your example doesn't fully function correctly, however, the style is a good example. I've swapped your under/overflow prevention on `currentSlide` to a modulo: `http://jsfiddle.net/M4t4L/14/`. Saves code and is pretty easy :-)

Comment: @DoXicK: If the question had not been closed I would have bothered to finish it. I simply could not remember of the modulus handled negatives correctly, as I normally do that, so went old-school :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie hehe, agreed. Modulo doesn't handle them btw, hence the `count + ...`. `(Count + -1) % Count` = `(5 - 1 ) % 5` = `4 % 5` = `4` :-)

Comment: @TrueBLueAussie prev/next button does not work correctly. Unfortunately each press is displayed, and then hiding the last slide

Comment: @BlahBlag: That was an incomplete example for you to play with. The question was closed so no point continuing with a new answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it fails with more than 3 slides is 'eq(2)'. Changed that to 'last()' and it now works.

Implementing prev() and next() is just a matter of switching the logic around. instead of appending the first to the list, prepend the last to the list to go backwards.

Updated the Fiddle to reflect the 'last()' change and also removed some useless stuff in there and cleaned it up a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/M4t4L/5/

```
$(function () {
    var container = $("#scene");
    container.find("li:first").css({
        "width": "100%"
    });
    $("#trigger").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(e);
        container.find("li")
            .finish()
            .removeClass('active')
            .last()
                .width(0)
                .addClass("active")
                .animate({ "width": "100%" }, 400, function () {
                    container.find("li").first().appendTo(container);
                });
    });
});
```